# Print task number in front of thread python?

Tags: python

I currently have a script which scrapes a CSV, then runs a function n times for n rows in the CSV, see code:

```
def link_check(product_link):
    response1 = requests.get(product_link, headers=headers)
    html1 = response1.content
    if something not in html1:
        print(row['Link'], "is an invalid link, check your link")
    else:
        function(product_link, product_name)



def function(product_link, product_name):
    response1 = requests.get(product_link, headers=headers)
    html1 = response1.content
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), "Monitoring", product_name)
    print(datetime.datetime.now(),
          'First HTML scraped successfully, sleeping')
# More code here which is not relevant



with open("tasks.csv", newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        if row['Name'] == "x":
            threading.Thread(target=link_check, args=(row['Link'],)).start()
        else:
            print("not available at this time")
```

I was wondering if it possible to print the thread number within function, or the row number in the form

`[Task 1] - 13:00:00:00 - First HTML scraped successfully sleeping`

Where the task number is the row number in the CSV (not including the headers row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the value of an incremental counter to the worker function as an argument:

```
from itertools import count

def link_check(product_link, task_number):
    response1 = requests.get(product_link, headers=headers)
    html1 = response1.content
    if something not in html1:
        print(row['Link'], "is an invalid link, check your link")
    else:
        function(product_link, product_name, task_number)

def function(product_link, product_name, task_number):
    response1 = requests.get(product_link, headers=headers)
    html1 = response1.content
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), "Monitoring", product_name)
    print(f'[Task {task_number}]', datetime.datetime.now(),
          'First HTML scraped successfully, sleeping', sep=' - ')

counter = count(1)
with open("tasks.csv", newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        if row['Name'] == "x":
            threading.Thread(target=link_check, args=(row['Link'], next(counter))).start()
        else:
            print("not available at this time")
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if it possible to print the thread number within
>   function

Yes, you can get the id of the current thread while it is executing a function. From [Threading python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.get_ident):

```
 threading.get_ident()
```

*Return the ‘thread identifier’ of the current thread. This is a nonzero integer. Its value has no direct meaning; it is intended as a magic cookie to be used e.g. to index a dictionary of thread-specific data. Thread identifiers may be recycled when a thread exits and another thread is created.*

You can also get the id with `threading.current_thread().ident`